# How to debug PyQt based applications in Spyder

Tags: python, spyder

I'm doing experience with my first small applications, essentially data viewers based on `Pandas` and `matplotlib`, using `PyQt` for the GUI part.

What I find now difficult is to understand what goes wrong in my code, because the error does not get propagated to the iPython console I launch my script from.
It simply won't do what's expected, but there is no information as to 'why'.

To fix ideas, let's say I have a button that should plot a certain curve to the canvas. If there's a fail in the indexing operation of the data, therefore nothing can be plotted, then nothing will appear on the canvas, but I'll get no traceback that actually index so-and-so wasn't to be found.

Using the debugger proves quite cumbersome, too.

I had a situation where, while running my `main()`, I could interact with the IPython shell and do things like:

```
main.my_plot_function()
```

from which I would get a standard output, and see what is wrong. Although sub-optimal, this did the trick.

I had to reset `Spyder` this morning (wasn't launching on Windows), and since then, when I launch my script, the console is unresponsive. So I can't do `main.my_plot_function()' anymore.

Generally speaking, is there a way to instruct `Spyder` or the console that I want to see what's going on in the background? Some "verbose" switch?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by wanting to know what's going on in the background. I assume that you wish to know at many points in the code, what the variable types and values are and/or where the current point of execution is.

There are two options:

1) Use print statements wherever you need to know what's going on. For example, if you have a plot function, simply put some print statements inside the function to print out the sizes of the lists/arrays being plotted etc. You can also look for useful functions in this regard, i.e., type() to print out the type of a variable to make sure it is what you think it is, print(locals()) to print names and values of all local variables etc.

2) Use [pdb](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) to introduce break points and run your main script from the command line. This will stop the script execution where you want and from the pdb console, you can inspect the data-structures. There are of course other debuggers you can use, such as [pudb](http://heather.cs.ucdavis.edu/~matloff/pudb.html) (with a basic GUI and some extra features than pdb).

There is no general "verbose" mode in spyder or any other Python IDE I know of.